# How can I read a txt file line by line and sort them by the correct variables and write them to another file?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Here is an example of my txt file

```
John
NY
2019
APR
Mark
SC
2019
JAN
Ava
CA
2018
AUG
```

Here is the example of the target txt file

```
Name,Location,Year,Month
John, NY,2019,APR
Mark, SC,2019,JAN
Ava,  CA,2018,AUG
```

The number of fields wont change. Basically how am I able to write a script that can identify that every 4th line is the month and the line after that is the name?

Comment: Are the spaces before the location field values significant? if not, a simple de-serialization using `paste` should be sufficient

Comment: This is very simple to do with `awk`, but please show what you've tried, and how it did not work as expected or intended.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble telling which of two potential questions you're asking - so I'll give both a broad shot, and if I get round to it, I'll look into the actual terminal / shell commands you might use tomorrow morning (and expand my answer then!).

So your question can either be understood as

- a): Sort a file from a "line by line" arrangement into a "table-like" (in your example its a **c**omma-**s**eparated-**v**alue file [also known as **csv**]) arrangement. That's effectively rather straightforward, and would require a loop structure (ie repeating the same set of instructions for each entry), and within that you would take the value's for the 4 lines that make up an entry (eg "John", "NY", "2019", "APR" ) and append them - in turn - to a new line, inserting commata (",") between the values.
- b): Sort the values of a file according to the type of variable and put everything back together in a nice sorted "table-like" arrangement (eg as a csv file, with the output looking much the same as described above). This is a good bit more tricky / complicated, but as long as your range of values/variables is restricted - as in your example (12 three letter abbreviations for months, 50 two letter abbreviations for US-States, etc.), then you can compare each of your values to the set/range of variables that is possible, and determine (relatively reliably) which kind of variable it is in that manner. And then of course, you put them together like beads on a string for your new file, just with a little more magic/ glue than as described above to get them in the right spot (that is, assuming as I have been here, that the values belonging to one entry are not always in the same order).

That's it for now - it would be nice to know which of the two above questions you meant before I go for an example terminal/shell input :D !

Regards, Sean Scherer

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any sorting involved here - just de-serialization into a fixed number (4) of columns. You can use

```
paste -d, - - - - < file
```

or

```
pr -aT -s, -4 < file
```

or

```
awk '{ORS = NR%4 ? "," : "\n"} 1' file
```

Ex.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "Name,Location,Year,Month"} {ORS = NR%4 ? "," : "\n"} 1' file
Name,Location,Year,Month
John,NY,2019,APR
Mark,SC,2019,JAN
Ava,CA,2018,AUG
```

Comment: is there a way to make it that it doesnt re-print the header every time? So every time i run it , the data is only added on. Right now it re-prints the header every time you run it.